# How do I enable and disable Android Nougat's "Work Mode" in Tasker?

Tags: android-7.0-nougat, tasker

How do I enable and disable Android Nougat's "Work Mode" in Tasker? Is there an intent I can send, or a setting I can change (using AutoTools if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

as I am still waiting for my s7 to get an OTA update to Nougat, I can only guess here as I did not have a possibility to tinker with that setting.

From what I could gather so far on the Internet there does not seem to be any Intent to switch on/off work mode. In that case your only option would be to automate the process of going into settings and clicking that option. You could use AutoInput for that